# Razor syntax @<text> blah blah </text>... what does it produce?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've looking at Telerik tools for MVC. They have a method of type Func and they are passing the content with this syntax...

```
Telerik.Factory().Content(@<text> content here </text>);
```

of course, it's more complex than that but i am just extracting the part that troubles me.

What exactly Razor is producing after @?

I've been trying to dig into using Google but can't find any useful info about it.

thanks.

Comment: a 2 second google search brings this up http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx

Comment: I already checked that before posting here. It really explains @ and @: / <text> which is pretty much the same. But i haven't been able to find anything where they actually use it @<text> </text>.

Comment: remove the whole telerik thing from MVC, its a how to make simple things really complicated framework.  @  is like a good old <%=   as in response.write

Comment: and also a marker for the start of a code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you feel difficult to understand is **Templated Razor Delegates**!

An example is...

```
@items.List(@<li>@item</li>)
```

There is a better post by @haacked that explains this.

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx